# Shadow of the parent view disappeared

Tags: html, css

Hi I am facing the shadow disappear issue when moving child `div` to below the `sticky` parent `div`.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        html, body{

         min-height: 100% !important;
        }

        body{

            margin: 0;
            background-color: #470c77;
        }

        .header{

            width:  100%;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px #000000;

            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
        }

        .view{

            width: 100%;
            height:25%;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            position: fixed;
            top: 50px;
            z-index: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="header">
         <!-- TODO:- Some elements here -->
         <div class="nav">
             <!-- TODO:- Some Elements Here -->
             <div class="view">

             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The main problem is shadow disappears from `nav`. If I make `top: 50px;` to `view` then the shadow appears. But background color of the body also visible.

current layout:
[image]

Expected Layout:

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem with CSS only.

Comment: You mean like this? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/bGdqPxg

Comment: @ManirajMurugan, Yes. Your solution works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: I have added it as answer with relevant details, feel free to accept if it solves your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve the `box-shadow` to a sticky element, then you need to use `:after` pseudo class and give the shadow there like,

```
  .header:after {
      z-index: -1;
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      bottom: 7px;
      left: auto;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px #000000;
  }
```

And modify the header class css like below snippet,

```css
        html, body{

         min-height: 100% !important;
        }

        body{

            margin: 0;
            background-color: #470c77;
        }

        .header{
            width:  100%;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
        }
      
          .header:after {
          z-index: -1;
          position: absolute;
          content: "";
          bottom: 7px;
          left: auto;
          width: 100%;
          top: 0;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px #000000;
         }

        .view{

            width: 100%;
            height:25%;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            position: fixed;
            top: 50px;
            z-index: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div class="header">
      <!-- TODO:- Some elements here -->
     <div class="nav">
         <!-- TODO:- Some Elements Here -->
         <div class="view">

         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        html, body{

         min-height: 100% !important;
        }

        body{

            margin: 0;
            background-color: #470c77;
        }

        .header{

            width:  100%;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -7px 3px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -7px 3px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
   box-shadow: inset 0 -7px 3px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
        }

        .view{

            width: 100%;
            height:25%;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            position: fixed;
            top: 50px;
            z-index: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="header">
         <!-- TODO:- Some elements here -->
         <div class="nav">
             <!-- TODO:- Some Elements Here -->
             <div class="view">

             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To hide the background, you can increase `.view` `height`

Answer (score 1):

So basically, the shadow wasn't removed or disappeared, it's just that it's hidden under the .view div. So here's what you gonna do, just remove the box-shadow on header since it's hidden, add update the background of your .view div. See my code below:

```css
html, body{
  min-height: 100% !important;
}

body{

  margin: 0;
  background-color: #470c77;
}

.header{
  width:  100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.view{
  width: 100%;
  height:25%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #999 0, #fff 7px, #fff 100%);
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="header">
         <!-- TODO:- Some elements here -->
         <div class="nav">
             <!-- TODO:- Some Elements Here -->
             <div class="view">

             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, anyway to bring up header over `.view`?

Comment: @MountAin just make the ".view" class a sibling of the header class then add the header class z-index: 1;.... You can't bring header over the view class since view is a child of header.  See this codepen anyway for you to view: https://codepen.io/jcarizon/pen/eYYXGqx

Comment: Or is it really necessary that the view is a child of header?

Comment: The solution above works provided by Maniraj. Thank you for your effort

Comment: Yeah no problem